# Python: max depth in binary tree

Tags: python, oop, binary-tree, depth

I have just introduced myself to oop and binary trees in Python, but I ran into problems while I tried to implement the max depth method. It does not seem to give me the right answer, it gives me 1 whereas the number should be much bigger or perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding something. I added a fraction of my code below

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.value = value
    self.count = 1

    def depth(self):
        if self.left:
            left_depth = self.left.depth()
        else:
            left_depth = 0
        right_depth = self.right.depth() if self.right else 0

        print(max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1)



tree = createTree(words) # list of words
tree.depth()
```

Comment: `print` isn't `return`.

Comment: as @user2357112 said above, you should `return` value, not `print` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        print(max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1)
```

should be...

```
        return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1
```

so that your `.depth()` method actually returns a value when called.

Then, at the end when you actually want a result:

```
print(tree.depth())
```

---

Also, it's a bit odd that you're using two different if-else constructs.

```
        left_depth = self.left.depth() if self.left else 0
        right_depth = self.right.depth() if self.right else 0
```

would work just fine and be more concise.